# Change the result to decimal in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to change the result of aggregate function in SQL Server 2012 to decimal

`M1` and `M2` are two columns in my table and their data type is `int`.

I need to find `sum(M1)/sum(M2)` and the result should be in 2 decimal places.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Select CAST((sum(M1)*100)/sum(M2)  as decimal(5,2)) as Total from dbo.tbl_Base base,dbo.tbl_Sample sample where 
sample .Period_ID=base.Period_ID

Comment: If you want to use `*100` 'tricks' then at least remember to also have the `/100`, while also being aware that the `/100` will also have an implicit type conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to cast both to decimals. The result will then be a decimal without other inferred type conversions

```
cast(sum(M1) as decimal(9,2))/cast(sum(M2) as decimal(9,2))
```

[Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the values before division. Please, read BOL article [Data Type Precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

```
CAST(SUM(M1) as DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(SUM(M2) as DECIMAL(10,2)
```